# Unable to connect to Portlet class from AJAX request .

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 CE for Portal Application development .
I am trying to Use Jquery with AJAX in my Portlet .
This is my JSP Page as shown :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.ajax({
url:'<portlet:resourceURL id="ajax" ></portlet:resourceURL>',
data: {id:data},
type: 'POST',
datatype:'json',
success: function(respData) {
alert(respData);
}
});
});
</script>
```

This is my MVC Portlet class

```
public class ArrayPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

@Resource(name="ajax")
public void testAjax(
PortletConfig config, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
throws Exception {


}
}
```

But i am unable to connect to my Java class .
Could somebody please help me . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
public class ArrayPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

@override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
throws Exception {


 }
}
```

Here you are overriding the serveResource method of the GenericPortlet class.